# Adding transparency to a widget - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I have a simple tkinter window which creates a simple gradient with the use of a canvas. The problem I have ran into is that whenever widgets are being placed on the window their background is appearing. I've tried messing with window attributes but have had no success. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
full_width, full_height = (root.winfo_screenwidth()), (root.winfo_screenheight())

def Startup(): #Gradient Left to right
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.lift()
    root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (full_width,full_height))
    colour1 = "#d785a5"
    colour2 = "#6b3d8f"
    width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    (r1,g1,b1) = root.winfo_rgb(colour1)
    (r2,g2,b2) = root.winfo_rgb(colour2)
    r_ratio = float(r2-r1) / full_width
    g_ratio = float(g2-g1) / full_width
    b_ratio = float(b2-b1) / full_width
    c = tk.Canvas(root, width = full_width, height = full_height)
    c.pack(side = tk.TOP, expand = True, fill = "both")
    c.update()
    for i in range(full_width):
        nr = int(r1 + (r_ratio * i))
        ng = int(g1 + (g_ratio * i))
        nb = int(b1 + (b_ratio * i))
        colour = "#%4.4x%4.4x%4.4x" % (nr,ng,nb)
        c.create_line(i, 0, i, full_height, fill = colour)
    root.option_add("*Font", "Helvetica")
    tk.Label(c, font=("Colonna MT", round(full_height/10)),text="Log in").pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="").pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="Username").pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="").pack()
    t = tk.Entry(c)
    t.pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="").pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="Password").pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="").pack()
    t2 = tk.Entry(c, show='*')
    t2.pack()
    tk.Label(c,text="").pack()
    tk.Button(c, text='Login', command= lambda:retrieve_input(t,t2)).pack() 

Startup()
```

Comment: Tkinter simply does not support transparency of widgets.  You can make canvas images transparent (but only with respect to other drawing items on the same canvas), and on some OSes you can make the entire window transparent, but that's it.

Comment: Not the reply I was hoping for but either way thanks for the reply